# What is the maximum length of a procedure name in delphi?

Tags: delphi

What is the longest name a procedure can be in character length?

Assume that it is not anything special like a dll export, just a procedure in a source file used by the program as usual...  how many characters would cause an error to occur?

```
procedure WhatLengthWillCauseIssuesIfItIsTooLong;
```

Answer (score 1):

255 characters.
You get a "Undeclared identifier" error if longer than 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in Delphi XE. It appears to be limited only by the maximum allowed length of a line in the PAS file, which is 1023 characters.